# SQL Compare data based on date rows into columns

Tags: sql, sql-server, date, compare, multiple-columns

Im very new to SQL,I have a SQL table that is as such

```
Name | Date                | performance_reading_1 | performance_reading_2     
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
BOB   2016-11-05 21:59:59     2000.000                 398776.000
JON   2016-11-05 23:59:59     2120.000                 118273.000
BOB   2016-11-06 13:59:59     3450.000                 228666.000
JON   2016-11-06 09:22:59     2432.000                 158643.000
BOB   2016-12-09 13:59:59     3450.000                 228666.000
JON   2016-12-11 09:22:59     2432.000                 158643.000
```

Basically I need a sql statement that will display in 1 row 2 different dates and the performance data for each date as such.

The 2 dates and the Name will vary and be passed in a variable.
I need to say Name $name on $date1 and $date2

```
Name | Date 1                | perf_1   | perf_2    | Date 2                  | perf_1   | perf_2
----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
BOB   2016-11-05 21:59:59     2000.000    398776.000   2016-12-09 13:59:59     3450.000    228666.000
```

Comment: What about third date?

Comment: It may come in handy for a third or forth date if it will still work if they are blank

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A self join would work well here:

```
DECLARE @Name varchar(50) = 'Bob'
DECLARE @Date1 datetime = '2016-11-05 21:59:59'
DECLARE @Date2 datetime = '2016-12-09 13:59:59'

SELECT T.Name,
       T.Date as 'Date1',
       T.Performance_Reading_1 as 'perf_1',
       T.Performance_Reading_2 as 'perf_2',
       T2.Date as 'Date2',
       T2.Performance_Reading_1 as 'perf_1',
       T2.Performance_Reading_2 as 'perf_2',
FROM YourTable T
INNER JOIN YourTable T2 on T.Name = T2.Name
WHERE T.Name = @Name
AND T.Date = @Date1
AND T2.Date = @Date2
```

PS Your aliases for each `Performance_Reading` are the same for each table, might get confusing..

Comment: Thanks! I will try this, Any way to easily remove the time from the date? for i can just specify for example '2016-11-05'

Comment: @catalyph Sure, just cast or convert in the `WHERE` clause if you feed in only a date.  ie. `AND CONVERT(date, T.Date) = @Date1`.  Only thing to note there is you could have duplicates without the timestamp, if for example, Bob has two records on the same day.

Comment: Thanks! this worked exactly as I needed it, I added a few tweaks as I needed them like extra column and it all works well, Thanks!

Comment: @catalyph Cool, happy to help :)

Comment: Is it possible to have @Name as a wildcard like * or Not Null ?

Comment: @catalyph Most definitely, but I don't quite follow...  What's the situation?  You want to have `WHERE T.name LIKE @Name`?  Or do you just want a default value for @Name?